# How to block requests querying specific parameters multiple times?

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

We have an web application written on Spring boot. On UI Angular is used. UI and backend talks via rest calls. Basically our rest endpoint returns a price based upon parameters sent.

Our concern is our rivals may reveal our price tariff by making requests with an automated system. Let me give you an example. See dummy requests below.

```
  {
    product: '1',
    age: '20',
    city: '10',
    gender: 'M',
    ...//some other params has no effect on price
  }
```

Let's say price in response is $100

```
  {
    product: '1',
    age: '21',
    city: '10',
    gender: 'M',
    ...//some other params has no effect on price
  }
```

Let's say price in response is $95

As seen, by changing age value customer gets $5 discount. We have many parameters has effect on price and many other doesn't effect price calculation.

What we want to do is :If a user makes requests in a specified time range more than x times by changing parameters (age, city etc.) having effect on calculation then block requests from that user for Y hours. If user changes only non-effective parameters than skip that and allow request.

I really don't know what search terms I can use. We want to produce a solution with Spring if possible.

Comment: How are you going to distinguish a rival user from a normal user? Do you want to block repetitive price evaluation for both of them?

Comment: Imagine I am a stupid user, and I thought age and city wouldn't affect the price - I made them up to complete the step faster. Now I see something wrong with the price, and I need to correct them immediately to see the actual price. Would I be rejected?

Comment: That is not the question. I will block anyone fitting situation.

Comment: This is basically a requirement for throttling requests, that is, limiting the number of requests from the same source, based on some criteria (such as "not more than 5 per hour"). There is nothing built into Spring MVC or Spring Boot (yet) to achieve this. However, others have come up with solutions using additional libraries. See [this](https://medium.com/teamarimac/implementing-throttling-in-java-spring-boot-ec4723cfce9f) as an example.

Comment: @manish very good keyword to start. I really appreciate. I'll look into details